# Illuminate\Database\QueryException in Laravel 6.0 but not in 5.8

Tags: laravel-6

I am having a problem with Laravel 6.0. The same source code is running ok with Laravel 5.8. The error is the following:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'XXXX' to data type int. (SQL: select * from [business_units] where [business_units].[code] in (0, 0, 0, 0))

Tried to create laravel project both using 5.8 and 6.0 containing the same source code but result is the same, running good in 5.8 but not in 6.0. Probably there is something wrong in Eloquent.

Here is the migration:

```
Schema::create('cost_centers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('code', 6)->primary();
            $table->string('descr', 50);
            $table->string('business_unit_code', 6)->index();
            $table->foreign('business_unit_code')->references('code')->on('business_units');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

My Model script is:

```
class CostCenter extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'code';
    protected $fillable = ['code', 'descr', 'business_unit_code'];

    public $incrementing = false;

    public function businessUnit()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BusinessUnit::class);
    }
}
```

This is after opening a form with the column in the table referencing another column where primary key is String. Did anybody encounter this problem, what is your resolution?

Answer (score 0):

In the table model "business_units", I change the declaration from 
This is necessary when using string as primary key.

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

to

```
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

This is specify in the Laravel upgrade guide as pointed to me by Sinnbeck of Laracast but somehow missed it.
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#eloquent-primary-key-type